# How to query database to fetch a child if its contents contain something?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a schema that looks like this. I want a database to return a child (post-ID) and its contents if `favoriteBy` contains the UID that I am looking for. Is this possible?

[image]

UID is defined by this variable:

```
private final String UID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

For reference, to fetch all user posts that were posted by the user, it would be fetched with this `Query` object:

```
databaseReference.child("user-posts").child(UID).limitToFirst(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase does not provide a lot of filtering tools to query data. So using only your current structure this won't be possible.

---

Without changing you current posts structure what I would recommend you to do is, whenever a user set a post as favorite you also updates another branch of your firebase database in a way you could easily get this data later.

So you can save the poster ownerUID and postID under the UID that had fav the post.

```
favoritedPosts: {
    UID: { //UID you are looking for
        postOwnerUID: {
            postID: true
        }
     }
}
```

Then you would easily get the favorited posts `postOwnerUID` and `postID` with something like:

```
databaseReference.child('favoritedPosts').child(UID)
```

The above query will return an object with `postOwnerUIDs` and their `postIDs` then finally you can iterate this object to retrieve the posts content with the IDs you have now.

```
databaseReference.child('user-posts').child(postOwnerUID).child(postID)
```

Comment: I kind of figured that this current schema wouldn't allow it. Just for clarification, you are saying this line: `databaseReference.child('favoritedPosts').child(UID)` should be saved as `ownerUID`?

Comment: @btramisetty No this is the UID of the user who have fav the post. The inner uid in your image.

Comment: If I fully understood it. The first Id you have on `/user-posts/uid` is the uid of the user who wrote the post (`postOwnerUID`). Then the inner UID in `favoritedBy` is the user who had favorited the post (`/favoritedPosts/UID`).

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a simple way to query the data in a way so that we can grab all the posts that the user favorited using the `.limitToFirst(100)` command to get the first 100 posts they favorited. I saved `favoritedBy->UIDs` in a separate tree also where the structure is: `postID -> [post attributes including favoriteBy->UIDs]`